# Visual Studio WebTestPlugin fails in calls to ReloadDataTable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, load-testing, web-testing

In a Visual Studio 2013 WebTestPlugin, I am attempting to change the Connection String of a Datasource in the WebTestPlugin PreWebTest event, and then calling WebTest.ReloadDataTable on each table in the Datasource.

I am getting unexpected results when calling WebTest.ReloadDataTable.  Is there any way to make this work?

When a DataSource of type Database is added to a WebTest one must set the Connection String statically for each DataSource.  In my solution I created each Datasource with a database connection string pointing to the Development database.  I have 3 Run Settings (Dev, QA, and Staging).  Each Run Setting has a "ConnectionString" ContextParameter which points to its own database.

Here is the code for my plugin.  It fetches the connection string from the Run Setting's ContextParameter, sets the DataSource to this connection string, then reloads the data tables in the datasource.

```
    public void PreWebTest(object sender, PreWebTestEventArgs e)
    {
        //fetch the connection string I want to use from the ContextParameter
        string connectionString = e.WebTest.Context["ConnectionString"].ToString();

        foreach (var ds in e.WebTest.DataSources)
        {

            if(ds.Connection.ToLower() != connectionString.ToLower())
            try
            {
        //point to the Datasource to my desired connection string
                ds.SetConnection("System.Data.SQLClient", connectionString);
                foreach (var table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    table.SelectColumns = DataBindingSelectColumns.SelectAllColumns;
                    //Visual Studio bug--the ReloadDataTable call runs on this datasource and table in this test, and then assumes the same datasource and table exists in every other test and tries to execute there, throwing an exception.
                    e.WebTest.ReloadDataTable(ds.Name, table.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(LogPath, string.Format("Error Web Test: {0}, ConnectionString {1} {2} {3}", e.WebTest.Name, connectionString, ex.ToString(), Environment.NewLine));
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, the call to e.WebTest.ReloadDataTable executes in every WebTest (not just the WebTest it is included in).  This happens even when I create a separate plugin for every WebTest.

For example, in my load test solution I have two web tests:

1. WebTestDog, with Datasource Dogs, tables GoodDogs and BadDogs
2. WebTestCat, with Datasource Cats, tables GoodCats and BadCats

I have two web test plugins with the PreWebTest method noted above:

1. WebTestDogPlugin, added to the WebTestDog test.
2. WebTestCatPlugin, added to the WebTestCat test.

When WebTestDog runs and invokes PreWebTest, this call executes:

```
e.WebTest.ReloadDataTable("Dogs", "GoodDogs")
```

And immediately throws an exception with this error message:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTestException:
>   ReloadDataTable failed: The data source 'Dogs' in Web test
>   'WebTestCat' does not contain a table with the name 'GoodDogs'

Why is Visual Studio executing this call in "WebTestCat" when I am in the PreWebTest event of "WebTestDog"?

I can think of a workaround, which is to add the Datasource "Dogs" to "WebTestCat."  But why do I have to do that?  In my actual solution, which has multiple tests, this will add a lot of clutter and will be confusing as all get-out to anyone who comes after me.

Comment: The workaround is for every web test to have an identical "DataSources" node, and every table in the datasource must have the "Select All Columns" setting for Select Columns.  The workaround adds clutter and useless overhead, but it works.

Comment: Correction, the workaround noted above does not work.  It runs without throwing an exception, but the tables are not reloaded with data from the new connection string, they keep the data that was loaded using the connection string they were created with.  Apparently the "ReloadDataTable" method simply does not do anything to the table data that is used by the web test.

Comment: See also [this Microsoft forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4c8a3587-538a-462b-be55-509b7ab70151/webtest-plugin-getting-properties-of-other-test?forum=vstest) where a very similar problem is discussed.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianHHH.  I wish it applied.  I verified that I'm calling (and only calling)  ReloadDataTable inside my desired test.  The problem is occurring inside the black box that holds the ReloadDataTable method, it is deciding to execute itself inside every web test.  But event if I get around that and add all datasources to all tests, the data tables still don't refresh.  Very frustrating.  I gave up.  My "workaround" is to use 3 different sets of tests, exact copies of one another except for the connection string.